# not able to install virtualbox-5.2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox

here is the message i'm getting while installation

> Running VMs found
>
> VirtualBox is currently running. Please close it and try again. Please
>   note that it can take up to ten seconds for VirtualBox (in particular
>   the VBoxSVC daemon) to finish running

[Screenshot of message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrXos.png)

Answer (score 0):

You commented that *`ps -e | grep -i virtualbox` is not showing anything*, so there is no currently running virtualbox process to stop. Try running `sudo apt install virtualbox-5.2` in a more isolated environment.

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GRUB menu. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GRUB screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.
2. From the GRUB screen select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

3. A new purple screen will appear showing a list of Linux kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

[image]

4. Use the arrow keys on the keyboard to select an earlier kernel version and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot with the selected kernel.
5. Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
6. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After you have logged in, you can run commands from the virtual console.
8. Install virtualbox-5.2.

   ```
       sudo apt remove virtualbox    
       sudo apt-get install --install-suggests virtualbox-5.2
   ```
9. To bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen run this command:

   ```
       sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```

Comment: ps -e | grep -i virtualbox is not showing anything